# Path Tracing Shadowing Error

Tags: raytracing, montecarlo

I really dont know what else do to to fix this problem.I have written a path tracer using explicit light sampling in c++ and I keep getting this weird really black shadows which I know is wrong.I have done everything to fix it but I still keep getting it,even on higher samples.What am I doing wrong ? Below is a image of the scene.

[image]

And The Radiance Main Code

```
RGB Radiance(Ray PixRay,std::vector<Primitive*> sceneObjects,int depth,std::vector<AreaLight> AreaLights,unsigned short *XI,int E)
{
    int MaxDepth = 10;

    if(depth > MaxDepth) return RGB();

    double nearest_t = INFINITY;
    Primitive* nearestObject = NULL;

    for(int i=0;i<sceneObjects.size();i++)
    {
        double root = sceneObjects[i]->intersect(PixRay);
        if(root > 0)
        {
            if(root < nearest_t)
            {
                nearest_t = root;
                nearestObject = sceneObjects[i];
            }
        }
    }

    RGB EstimatedRadiance;

    if(nearestObject)
    {    
        EstimatedRadiance = nearestObject->getEmission() * E;    
        Point intersectPoint = nearestObject->intersectPoint(PixRay,nearest_t);
        Vector intersectNormal = nearestObject->surfacePointNormal(intersectPoint).Normalize();

        if(nearestObject->getBRDF().Type == 1)
        {    
            for(int x=0;x<AreaLights.size();x++)
            {

                Point pointOnTriangle = RandomPointOnTriangle(AreaLights[x].shape,XI);
                Vector pointOnTriangleNormal = AreaLights[x].shape.surfacePointNormal(pointOnTriangle).Normalize();
                Vector LightDistance = (pointOnTriangle - intersectPoint).Normalize();

                //Geometric Term
                RGB Geometric_Term = GeometricTerm(intersectPoint,pointOnTriangle,sceneObjects);
                //Lambertian BRDF
                RGB LambertianBRDF =  nearestObject->getColor() * (1. / M_PI);
                //Emitted Light Power
                RGB Emission = AreaLights[x].emission;

                double MagnitudeOfXandY = (pointOnTriangle - intersectPoint).Magnitude() * (pointOnTriangle - intersectPoint).Magnitude();
                RGB DirectLight = Emission * LambertianBRDF  * Dot(intersectNormal,-LightDistance) * 
                    Dot(pointOnTriangleNormal,LightDistance) * (1./MagnitudeOfXandY) * AreaLights[x].shape.Area() * Geometric_Term;

                EstimatedRadiance = EstimatedRadiance + DirectLight;
            }
            //
            Vector diffDir = CosWeightedRandHemiDirection(intersectNormal,XI);
            Ray diffRay = Ray(intersectPoint,diffDir);    
            EstimatedRadiance = EstimatedRadiance + ( Radiance(diffRay,sceneObjects,depth+1,AreaLights,XI,0) * nearestObject->getColor() * (1. / M_PI) * M_PI );    
        }

        //Mirror
        else if(nearestObject->getBRDF().Type == 2)
        {
            Vector reflDir = PixRay.d-intersectNormal*2*Dot(intersectNormal,PixRay.d);
            Ray reflRay = Ray(intersectPoint,reflDir);

            return nearestObject->getColor() *Radiance(reflRay,sceneObjects,depth+1,AreaLights,XI,0);
        }
    }

    return EstimatedRadiance;    
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NRm.jpg

Comment: Forgive me.This is my first time asking a question.The link to the image is http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NRm.jpg

Comment: If you can share a few relevant lines of code, that can also be helpful. This will work best, if you use the code button in the editor (curly braces) or indent the code with four (or more) spaces. Then it will be formatted as code quite nicely! Welcome on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: This looks like a really nice question. I'm not much of a c++ person, but i hope you get a few upvotes - and hopefully a helpful answer! Cheers!

Comment: Also, you could add the image link to the post by clicking "edit".  Sometimes people don't necessarily read through the comments when looking at a question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't debugged your code, so there may be any number of bugs of course, but I can give you some tips: First, go look at [SmallPT](http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/), and see what it does that you don't. It's tiny but still quite easy to read.

From the look of it, it seems there are issues with either the sampling and/or gamma correction. The easiest one is gamma: when converting RGB intensity in the range 0..1 to RGB in the range 0..255, remember to always gamma correct. Use a gamma of 2.2

```
R = r^(1.0/gamma)
G = g^(1.0/gamma)
B = b^(1.0/gamma)
```

Having the wrong gamma will make any path traced image look bad.
Second: sampling. It's not obvious from the code how the sampling is weighted. I'm only familiar with Path Tracing using russian roulette sampling. With RR the radiance basically works like so:

```
  if (depth > MaxDepth)
     return RGB();

  RGB color = mat.Emission;

  // Russian roulette:
  float survival = 1.0f;
  float pContinue = material.Albedo();
  survival = 1.0f / pContinue;
  if (Rand.Next() > pContinue)
     return color;

  color += DirectIllumination(sceneIntersection);
  color += Radiance(sceneIntersection, depth+1) * survival;
```

RR is basically a way of terminating rays at random, but still maintaining an unbiased estimate of the true radiance. Since it adds a weight to the indirect term, and the shadow and bottom of the speheres are only indirectly lit, I'd suspect that has something to do with it (if it isn't just the gamma).

Comment: I have already added the gamma correction and clamping functions from smallPT as well as the Russian Roulette Code from smallPT.It was still not working.I just decided to remove it.But I would try again and see.Thanks for your help.